# Webmethod Stops Working

Tags: c#, jquery, webmethod

I,m trying to pass value from jquery to webmethod. but when ever 1 pass value webmethod does not starts. and when i remove the passing value code it starts working properly What is the problem?
JS code.

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ContryCityDDL.aspx/GetCountry",
        data: '{}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (r) {
            var ddlcontry = $("[id*=ddlcontry]");
            ddlcontry.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Please select</option>');
            $.each(r.d, function () {
                ddlcontry.append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
            });
        }
    });

    $("#ddlcontry").change(function () {
        alert($('option:selected', $(this)).val());
       var countyId = $(this).val();

        $("#HiddenField1").val($('option:selected', $(this)).val());


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ContryCityDDL.aspx/GetCity&countryId='"+countryId+"'",
            data: '{}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (r) {
                var ddlcity = $("[id*=ddlcity]");
                ddlcity.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Please select</option>');
                $.each(r.d, function () {
                    ddlcity.append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

C#

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<ListItem> GetCity(string countryId)
{

    string constrng;
            string query = "Select CityId,CityName From City"; 
    //string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;

     constrng = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;AttachDbFilename='C:\\Users\\Abdul Basit Mehmood\\Desktop\\DropdownAJAX\\DropdownAJAX\\App_Data\\ContryCity.mdf';Integrated Security=True";

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constrng))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
        {
            List<ListItem> customers = new List<ListItem>();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    customers.Add(new ListItem
                    {
                        Value = sdr["CityId"].ToString(),
                        Text = sdr["CityName"].ToString()
                    });
                }
            }
            con.Close();
            return customers;
        }
    }
}
```

when i remove 'string `countryId'` from c# code and  `var countyId = $(this).val();&countryId='"+countryId+"'" from js the code runs properly.

Comment: Please somebody can tell me why GetCity(string countryId) not working. What is the issu when i want to read some arguments in the function. Changing in js is not making any difference

Answer (score 2):

You want to pass the `ContryId` as query string from your ajax call and in that case use `?` character and not `&` like

```
"ContryCityDDL.aspx/GetCity?countryId='"
```

Comment: Compiler is not showing any error but problem is that GetCity() function is running properly but when i change it to GetCity(string countryId) it doesn,t run. I need countryId to populate city dropdown list on the basis of selected country.

Comment: @AbdulBasitMehmood, compiler won't show error for client code ... means JS code

Comment: Why is GetCity(string countryId) not working while GetCity() is working?

Comment: Please somebody can tell me why GetCity(string countryId) not working. What is the issu when i want to read some arguments in the function. Changing in js is not making any difference.

Answer (score 0):

try this on ddlcontry change function,

```
 $("#ddlcontry").change(function () {
            alert($('option:selected', $(this)).val());
            var countryId = $(this).val();

            $("#HiddenField1").val($('option:selected', $(this)).val());


            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ContryCityDDL.aspx/GetCity",
                data: "{'countryId':'" + countryId + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (r) {
                    var ddlcity = $("[id*=ddlcity]");
                    ddlcity.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Please select</option>');
                    $.each(r.d, function () {
                        ddlcity.append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

hope this is working.